# How can I exit a custom multiplayer game after the countdown has started?

Tags: starcraft-2

This is really annoying. Sometimes I want to leave a custom multiplayer game just after the countdown has started. For example if I misclicked and join some weird map I do not want to play but the game automatically starts.

Some time ago there was a leave or cancel button I could click before the second countdown started, but somehow I cannot find it anymore. The real cancel button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Can't check right now but does ESC or F10 work to open up the menu and get the chance go LOGOUT?

Comment: The technology just isn't there yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually hit F10 and choose "Logout."

This prevents you from having to restart the entire game, at least.

Comment: The "Menu" menu at the lower left is still available during a countdown, so you can click logout from there, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to exit just the lobby, the short answer is: **You can't**.

Ways to get out of the game at all costs:

1. **Exit the entire game** 
   A. You can <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> 
   B. You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> 
   C. You can turn off your computer (I.E. Hold Power Button)
2. **Exit the game after it starts.**

**As a side note**

 The cancel button appears (In the picture) on the top, not the bottom. And whenever the countdown starts no one can leave the game. This prevents people from having unbalanced teams.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> is always a viable option
or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and shutdown the game via Task Manager